# ffmpg voice + base - base must end when the entry with the cut at the beginning ends

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, mp3, podcasts

I'm experimenting with a bat command to manage audio tracks.
My goal is to create tracks with vocals and music for a podcast. I managed to mix the file which contains only one recording of the voice, and with ffmpeg's automatic mechanisms, add the backing track which is cut when the voice track ends.
But I would like the base cut, to adapt to the first track, to happen at the beginning and not at the end so as to always have the correct base closing when the speech ends.
What command can I tell ffmpeg to do this with?
I do not know if I was clear.
therefore each processed vocal track will become a mix track with the base (at 40% volume) which will end exactly with the end of the base and not with a cut.
For example, I have a 5-minute vocal track, then I have an 8-minute backing track ready, I would like the cut to adapt the backing track to speech to take place in the first 3 minutes and not in the last 3
thank you very much for anyone who can help me.
I now use this one but it cuts to the bottom:

`ffmpeg -i 4voice4.mp3 -i base.mp3 -filter_complex "[0:a]volume=1.0[a];[1:a]adelay=0s|10s[a2];[a2]volume=0.4[b]; [a][b]amix=inputs=2:duration=first" -c:a libmp3lame -y output.mp3`

Comment: Why don't you do this in a proper audio editor rather than try do it all from command-line? That way you can hear what you're doing before you commit.

Comment: this work it's for a web radio. I have several podcasters who send me their vocals for their recorded program and, with an audio editor program, I have to insert the base under the voice and then manually proceed with uploading it to the radio server.
Instead, I want to create an automatism that takes the voice file, arranges it and adds the base, then once saved, the radio program will load it at the right time.
So I save a lot of work and time

Comment: So… you want to run a radio station without ever having to listen to your program output?  Words cannot express just how poor an idea I think that is. Wish you luck.

Comment: yes, but i shure for voice quality track and i need only to accelerate the worke

Comment: This is how easy it is to do properly - Two copies of your sound bed, you slide one to match your voiceover start [I gave it a bit of musical intro here, just as an example], the other to match your end - so you always get your closing sting. then all you need is a cross-fade somewhere in the middle, where no-one will notice. You can set this all up in the time it takes to listen to your voiceover **once**. Export takes seconds. https://i.stack.imgur.com/lOldR.png

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but I know how to edit audio with editing programs. I need commands to do this with ffmpg on the command line.
So know how to align the tracks at the end and not at the beginning